# How to compile X86 assembly and call its function in Linux

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am testing an X86 assembly code in Ubuntu 18.04 X86_64 as follows,

```
    #define I8042_DATA_REG          $0x60
    #define I8042_STATUS_REG        $0x64

    .globl   flashy

    .text
    /* Flash 16 times */
    movl    $0x10, %ebx
    flashy:
    /* Turn on LEDs, don't trust stack at this point */
    1:  inb     I8042_STATUS_REG, %al
    testb   $0x02, %al
    jne     1b
    movb    $0xed, %al
    outb    %al, I8042_DATA_REG

    movl    $0x1000, %eax
    1:  subl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    $0, %eax
    jne     1b

    1:  inb     I8042_STATUS_REG, %al
    testb   $0x02, %al
    jne     1b

    movl    $0x1000, %eax
    1:  subl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    $0, %eax
    jne     1b

    /* LEDs ON */
    movb    $0x07, %al
    outb    %al, I8042_DATA_REG

    /* delay */
    movl    $0x07878787, %eax
    1:  subl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    $0, %eax
    jne     1b

    sub     $1, %ebx
    cmpl    $0, %ebx
    jne     flashy
```

And i write a simple main.c to call the flashy() function in above assembly.

```
    extern void flashy(void);

    int main()
    {
        flashy();
        return 0;
    }
```

I compiled them as,

```
gcc -S test.S -o test.o  
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
ld main.o test.o -o testmain
```

I got a warning from ld as follows,
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
And I can not run the generated testmain.

So I want to know what I missed in building this test.

Comment: Use `gcc` for linking instead of `ld`, `gcc` will automatically link the standard library for C programs. BTW, I think your assembly code will not work in user mode as interacting directly with hardware requires ring 0, consider use an emulator like DosBox.

Comment: Please add your main.c code here, and show your command to build and run it.

Comment: @KagurazakaKotori you gave me the right answer. By following your comment, I also added iopl(3)/iopl(0) around flashy(), and with gcc I can run this code well. You can publish your answer or I can publish your answer in your name.

Comment: @wangt13 Please feel free to publish the answer.

Comment: Why is `movl    $0x10, %ebx` located before the `flashy` label?  Also, as a general stylistic note: labels go into the first column, with no indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I published the answer from KagurazakaKotori.  The commands to build an executive in Linux from *.S and *.c file.

```
gcc -c test.S -o test.o  
gcc -c main.c -o main.o  
gcc test.o main.o -o testmain
```